# Configuring Juniper EX2200 Ethernet-Switching

Tags: networking, routing, switch, ethernet, juniper

Recently I started configuring an Juniper EX2200 to be used with an fibre optic connection  in it's SFP module.
The switch itself is online and can ping remote hosts without an issue after setting the IP provided by our ISP on the right interface and configuring a route to our default gateway. 
There is also VLAN with most of the port assigned to it and a DHCP server handing out addresses in that VLAN.

The issue is that none of the endpoints plugged into the ethernet ports can get an internet connection. They get the DHCP setting and are able to ping the switch but no further then that.
I've looked around but I can figure out how I can route all the ethernet ports in the VLAN to the connection of the SFP port.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have routing configured for your VLAN endpoints.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on the question? If you already solved the problem, please answer your own question and accept it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your DHCP server is handing out private IP addresses and you need to configure network address translation (NAT) to make Internet connectivity possible. To help you further, we need configuration files and/or more details on how you've setup your network.